# Cant deploy web app because of version conflict, however it runs fine locally

Tags: visual-studio, web-deployment, webdeploy

I have an ASP.net core web app which references a DLL called BLL, which in turn references a DLL called DAL, and within the DAL there is a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.2.

I have changed the .net versions of these 3 projects from 6 to 7 today, it all compiles and runs fine locally in Visual Studio.

However when I come to deploy it the BLL won't compile, I get an error:

Error   CS1705  Assembly 'ST.CMS.DAL' with identity 'ST.CMS.DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=**7.0.2.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' with identity 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=**6.0.2.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'    ST.CMS.BLL  C:\Users******\ST.CMS\ST.CMS.BLL\CSC   1   Active

So there is a conflict between 6.0.2 and 7.0.2 for EntityFrameworkCore, however i'm not using 6.0.2 anywhere, I can't understand where it's getting 6.0.2 from.

Before I did this change today it deployed fine. I have tried closing and reopening Visual Studio and rebooting the laptop but it still keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the Nuget package references to Entity framework core in the DAL project then re-adding them solved the problem.